# Finding the equilibrium points of a 3D system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I've only done this for 2D systems, never for 3D.

Find the equilibrium points for this system of equations (your answer will depend on the value of $N=S+I+R$, which you may assume to be a constant). ($a,b,c$ are positive constants.)
$$\dot S=cR - aSI$$
$$\dot I = aSI - bI$$
$$\dot R = bI - cR$$

> My attempt:
>
> From $\dot I = aSI - bI$, if $\dot I =0$, then $aSI = bI \therefore I = 0$ or $S = \frac{b}{a}$
>
> If $I = 0$, then by $\dot R$, $R=0$, and $S$ could be any value, therefore $(S,I,R)=(k,0,0)$ is a fixed point for any $k \in [0,N]$.
>
> > Is this remotely somwhere along the lines of what this question is asking?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're following exactly the right approach. 
Now you can try to find any other equilibrium points by taking the second choice which yields $\dot{I} = 0$, namely $S = \frac{b}{a}$, and repeat the line of reasoning you already employed. Hint: you will obtain two distinct 'lines' of equilibria (you already found one of them).